# Can we install Ubuntu Server on Lenovo sr530 with Intel Xeon silver processor?

Tags: server

I have a server.It's configuration details details as below

```
Lenovo sr530 
Intel Xeon silver processor
RAM 16gb
hdd 2tb
```

My Question is can I install Ubuntu Server on this server and host my applications on it?

Comment: The above Link I checked but it is related to ubuntu only not for ubuntu server

Comment: This general question is related to both Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server, and it is related to all *buntu derivatives too. There is nothing in the accepted answer to the linked question that is exclusive to either one specific Ubuntu version or release date.

Comment: I asked this question regarding ubuntu server.Not for ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, you can install Ubuntu on that server!

Comment: not satisfied yet because I again saying that  it is not r elated to ubuntu ,it is ubuntu server

Comment: I'm not satisfied either because there are thousands of different computer models out there and we can't support a unique question for each model, not even for yours, because this describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The Lenovo SR530 is in the list of certified systems for Ubuntu Server 18.04:

https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201706-25573/

Comment: thanks for given info but I inform you that information given in the link is for the intel xeon platinum processor and my config is different.

Comment: Strictly speaking, nobody can answer your question without trying your specific version of Ubuntu (that you didn't state: 18.04? Other? which patch level?) on your very specific hardware. But in general, the show-stoppers are peripherals (network and disk adapters), but these are the same in variants of the servers, and recent CPUs (but this is a more a matter of kernel support, so just check if your CPU is supported by the kernel used).